# same path active class showing double in react

Tags: reactjs, class

I used `isActive` in `NavLink` with the same path URL as like:

`dashboard` and `dashboard/home` , when I visit `dashboard` its okay to showing active class but when I visit `dashboard/home` both `NavLink` is showing active class.

Here is my code:

```
  <NavLink
    className={({ isActive }) =>
      `sidebar-link d-flex align-items-center ${
        isActive && "sidebar-link-active"
      }`
    }
    to={to}
    onClick={handleClose}
  >
    {icon}
    <span className="ms-2">{text}</span>
  </NavLink>
```

I think `dashboard` and `dashboard/home` both path found `dashboard` that's why it conflicting but I want individuals active class.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `exact` attribute in your Routes can fix this

Comment: I tried this but still same problem